# Convert non-ISO string containing date, time and timezone to UTC datetime

Tags: python

I have a string (which initially appeared to be in ISO format) representing a date and time, with timezone:

```
"2021-12-15T20:40:39.718-0500"
```

and i'm trying to use this code:

```
import datetime

str = "2021-12-15T20:40:39.718-0500"
dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(str)
```

to convert it to a datetime (and eventually a datetime in UTC).

However, it seems the string is not correct ISO format:

```
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2021-12-15T20:40:39.718-0500'
```

I believe there should be a colon between the hours and minutes in the timezone:

```
str = "2021-12-15T20:40:39.718-05:00"
```

Is there any way to retrieve a UTC datetime without resorting to nasty string parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime` which, `%z` recognizes timezones without ":" or if using a 3rd party library is more appealing, python-dateutil `dateutil.parse.isoparse` works straight out of the box. Timezone conversion is afterwards easy with `.astimezone` method:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

date_str = "2021-12-15T20:40:39.718-0500"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print(dt)
# Alternative with dateutil
dt = dateutil.parser.isoparse(date_str)
print(dt)
dt = dt.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
print(dt)
```

Comment: I *knew* there had to be a predefined instance for UTC!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strptime`; the `%z` format matches timezones without colons.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str = "2021-12-15T20:40:39.718-0500"
>>> datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 15, 20, 40, 39, 718000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)))
```

Now you have a `datetime` instance, but it preserves the original non-UTC timezone. To convert it, use the `astimezone` method.

```
>>> from datetime import timezone, timedelta
>>> d = datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
>>> d.astimezone(timezone(timedelta(0)))
datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 16, 1, 40, 39, 718000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

(I feel like I am overlooking something much simpler, but this works.)

Update: as Tzane points out, `timezone(timedelta(0))` is predefined as `timezone.utc`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. RE the last line, there's no way I can just assign the 3rd line to a variable and pass that to the datetime ctor??

Comment: Accepted the other answer but gave you two upvotes

Comment: You should accept the other answer :) It provided the sane way of calling `dt.astimezone` first.